# What is a more general word for 'airport' and 'train station'?

Tags: vocabulary

I am designing an application, and I am looking to group these two entities (airports and train stations) into one category. The primary meaning of `station` seems to be for trains, and `air station` seems to refer to military airfields.

Is there a word that can be used in place of both an airport and a train station?

Comment: Your question is confusing to me. Are you looking for a word that combines airports and railway stations(the title) or a word that refers to beginning/end of a route?(the body)

Comment: Sorry. I edited the question. I need the one in the title (i.e. airports and railway stations).

Comment: @BiscuitBoy I disagree. There is a difference between the end points of a route and stops along the way (at least in the US). The referenced question only deals with end points.

Comment: @bib - I couldn't tell any difference so I flagged it as a dupe. I thought it will still need 4 more votes from other users to be fully "marked as duplicate" but I didn't know Community user could vote as well! And apparently only one vote is required from diamond users. How should this be handled?

Comment: I chose to mark it as duplicate since a button was being displayed to me. I thought the answer of that question also answers my own question. Seems I was wrong. Sorry.

Answer (score 4):

*Transit hub* or *transport hub* would fit the bill. *Station* is quite general (e.g. *bus station* but you're right in that it wouldn't suggest an airport).

A *hub airport* is something more specific - one which connects long- and short-distance flights.

The beginning/end of a route could be a *terminus* (mainly land-based transport). A connection between routes could be an *interchange*. The same hub could be both depending on the traveller's journey.

Comment: I was starting to create that same answer, when I saw the duplicate on the "RELATED" panel on the right of the page!

Comment: @Graffito the mobile version of the site (which I was on a few minutes ago) doesn't give that panel.

Comment: Hub seems to imply that the purpose for its existence is to exchange. "A transport hub (also transport interchange) is a place where passengers and cargo are exchanged between vehicles or between transport modes." Am I right?

Comment: @ParhamDoustdar, you have to get to the station somehow, even if on foot.  But no, altough a hub is a junction between routes, it's not *only* a junction between routes.

Answer (score 3):

How about ***terminal***?

> station where transport vehicles load or unload passengers or goods [WordNet by Farlex](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Terminal)

Comment: In the US, in discussing train stations, terminal is usually reserved for the station that is at the end of a line (where the line terminates).

Comment: Is there a word that does not imply the endpoint of a route?

Answer (score 1):

If your application is using these entities only in the context of journeys, perhaps **point of embarkation** or  **point of origin** may work.

Quoting http://www.travel-industry-dictionary.com/point-of-embarkation.html

> point of embarkation, point of origin. Where a journey begins.

EDIT: update after comment ...
http://www.thefreedictionary.com/disembarkation
has an example

> The company's 2003 revised Cruise Atlas, due out shortly, contains a listing of over two hundred approved **embarkation and disembarkation ports**, daily rates, plus complete terms and conditions of the program.

So, I guess one could say stations or airports are **embarkation/disembarkation points**.

Comment: I don't want to imply that this is only for the origin. This could also be a destination.